# Where can I find the Handover Protocol setting on the new Facebook Meta Business Suite?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

One of the pages I manage has been updated to the new UI and I could not find the setting anymore.

The setting can be found here before the UI update. https://flow.ai/blog/handle-facebook-messenger-handovers

Comment: Does [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol)  help